# Protecting system databases in Sql Server Management Studio?

Tags: ssms, default-database

For the five hundredth time, I ran a sql script in management studio to add some tables to a database and FORGOT TO CHANGE THE DATABASE IT RUNS AGAINST.  Since it defaults to `master`, I had to go and drop all the new tables I just added.

I practically never run sql scripts against the `master` database or other system databases, yet in Management Studio not only are they available in the combo box as a viable target for my scripts, but `master` is the default option.

Is there any way to remove system databases from this dropdown?  Or, at least, change the default database from `master`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default database for your login to SQL Server is set to master.  Change it to the database that you use most frequently.

Comment: I love blatantly obvious and simple answers.